# SQL count non sequential dates

Tags: ms-access, count

Here's the data:

```
empID Date     Type
----- -------- ----
    1 1/1/2012  u
    1 1/2/2012  u
    1 1/3/2012  u
    1 2/2/2012  u
    4 1/1/2012  u
    4 1/3/2012  u
    4 1/4/2012  u
    4 1/6/2012  u
```

Would return:

```
empID count
----- -----
    1     2
    4     3
```

When two dates are "together" they count as one occurrence, if the dates are separated out, they count as two occurrences.  This is for tracking employee attendance...  how would the SQL statement look to group by "together" dates and count them as 1... I'm really struggling with the logic.

Comment: This is actually in Access 10 ... I have nothing worked out so far... weekends don't matter.... the data are entered manually, I just need logic to "build" occurances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    empID
  , COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM 
    tableX AS x
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM tableX AS y
          WHERE y.empID = x.empID
            AND DATEADD ("d", -1, x.[Date]) = y.[Date]
        )
GROUP BY
    empID ;
```

Comment: Here is what I have and I get a syntax error: <pre>SELECT 
    TechID
  , COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM 
    tblOccurances AS x
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
          FROM tblOccurances AS y
          WHERE y.TechID = x.TechID
            DATEADD ("d", -1, x.[OccuranceDate]) = y.[OccuranceDate]
        )
GROUP BY
    TechID <code>

Comment: You forgot an `AND`: `WHERE y.TechID = x.TechID AND DATEADD ...`

Comment: To write code in the comments, use backticks: This `\`AND\`` is shown as: `AND`

Comment: so how would I add one caveat to this?  I need to only look for the "occurrences" for a rolling 6 month's previous to today's date.  I don't care about any occurrences previous to today as those roll off the employee's record

Comment: You could add an additional condition on the `WHERE (x.[Date] BETWEEN ... AND ...) AND NOT EXISTS ...` the rest stays as is.

Comment: How could I have it automatically populate those dates from 6-months previous to today's date?

Comment: I believe you can specify Now() as one end of your bounds, and Now()-180 to be roughly six months (180 days) prior to today (as Now() reports when used)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
;WITH CTE as
(select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by empID order by date) as rn from test2 t1)

select empID,COUNT(*) as count
from CTE c1
where isnull((DATEDIFF(day,(select date from CTE where c1.rn=rn+1 and empID=c1.empID ),c1.date)),0) <> 1
group by empID
```

Comment: Not in MS Access, which is what the user requested. SQL is a generic tag.